# Which SQL platform is this code?

Tags: sql

I'm not familiar with SQL.. i need to open one dataset, but i need to figure out which sql platform should i use.. There is a README file to view this dataset correctly, and there is one of the steps;

Example SQL code:

/* LOAD ATTRIBUTE FILE */

```
BULK INSERT [<DATABASE>].[<OWNER>].[<TABLE NAME>]
FROM 'PATH\TO\LPS_ATTRIBUTES_<FIPS>.txt'
WITH (
     FORMATFILE = 'PATH\TO\LPS_CUSTOM_ATTRIBUTES_v1.fmt'
     )
```

I've tried Access and PostgreSQL, `BULK INSERT` command doesn't work for them..

Comment: Have you tried to google "bulk insert"?

Comment: What does a search on the phrase `BULK INSERT` return for you?

Comment: Looks like Microsoft SQL Server. But usually you chose the Database System first...

Comment: As it is a .TXT file, I'd open it with any text editor. Anyway, this requirement of yours certainly sounds strange. Do you really have all those databases available so that you can try all of them, seeing which one might accept your BULK INSERT attempt?

Comment: @Littlefoot in dataset there is a README file and this code one of the steps to view data correctly. Ofs i can open txt file with any text editor.. but there is a formatfile i need to add table with the txt file.

Comment: @jarlh yes i have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it really seems to be MS SQL Server: [Use a Format File to Bulk Import Data (SQL Server)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/use-a-format-file-to-bulk-import-data-sql-server)

Example says:

```
USE TestDatabase;  
GO

TRUNCATE TABLE myFirstImport; -- (for testing)
BULK INSERT dbo.myFirstImport   
   FROM 'D:\BCP\myFirstImport.bcp'   
   WITH (FORMATFILE = 'D:\BCP\myFirstImport.xml');  
GO
```

which is really close to what you have.